# $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\int_0^1 3y+2(1-y)^xdy\right)^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\int_0^1 \left(3y+2(1-y)^x\right)  dy\right)^{1/x}$$

I was solving this problem, and when I solve I got the answer which the software says incorrect.

**My try:**
Firstly, the simplest approach I directly solved the integration to get
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3x+7}{2x+2}\right)^{\frac1x}=3.5^{\pm \infty}$$ not unique, so i thought it should be $\color{blue}{\text{Does not Exist}}$

Next approach was to use the shortcut formula of $1^\infty$ form involving exponent directly which gives me answer as $\frac1e$ which is also incorrect but later I feel it should be incorrect because when x tends to zero, the inner integral is not tends to 1.

> Furthermore, if put the limit at the very start, I wanna know out of those 7 indeterminate forms $\color{red}{\text{Which form is this limit ?}}$

**Do you also think the question is wrong ?**

Comment: I did that and got 1/e as answer which was also wrong

Comment: @fGDu94 you cannot apply l'hopital on the exponent because the numerator does not go to $0$ or $\pm \infty$.

Comment: exactly, we dont have here 0/0 or inf/inf form

Comment: Your try is correct. The limit indeed does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure you got the problem right? I've got the same answer as your first approach

Comment: @AmanRajput there is no "$1^\infty$", so I am not sure what you did to arrive at $1/e$. There is no indeterminate form at all, so you will not find it among the 7 forms.

Comment: As written, you are correct, the integral doesn’t exist. Is maybe the integrand supposed to be $$(3y+2)(1-y)^x?$$

Comment: I only ask because, as written, the integral is missing parentheses. As written, it should be $$\int_0^1\left(3y+2(1-y)^x\right)\,dy$$

Comment: @nexball yes true I mentioned above that I realised later integrand is not coming 1 as y is variable

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no limit. Solving the integral you have
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \int_{0}^{1} 3y+2(1-y)^{x}dy 
    & = &    \int_{0}^{1} 3ydy+\int_{0}^{1}2(1-y)^{x}dy\\
    & = &    \left.\left(\frac{3y^{2}}{2}-2\frac{(1−y)^{x+1}}{x+1}\right) 
\right|_{0}^{1}\\
    & = &    \frac{3}{2} + \frac{2}{x+1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Then we calculate the limit with $x=1/y$ a change of variable,
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \lim_{x\to0^{\pm}}\left(\frac{3}{2} + \frac{2}{x+1}\right)^{1/x}
    & = &    \lim_{x\to0^{\pm}}\left(\frac{3x+7}{2x+2}\right)^{1/x}\\
    & = &    \lim_{y\to\pm\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{3}{y}+7}{\frac{2}{y}+2}\right)^{y}\\
    & = &    \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^{\pm\infty}
\end{eqnarray*}

this tiends to $0$ or $\infty$ depending on the sign, i.e. $(7/2)^{x}\to \infty$ when $x\to\infty$ and $(7/2)^{x}\to0$ when $x\to-\infty$

Comment: what did you do to $e^{x \ln(1-y)}$?

Comment: Oh excuse me, I confused the sum property inside the exponential

Comment: Yes, no problem, sorry for the confusion above

Comment: You’ve also lost the $2.$ It should be $$\frac32+\frac2{x+1}=\frac{3x+7}{2x+2}$$ which just reproduces what OP got.

Comment: So you just did the same as I did. And obtain same result. Thanks for trying

Comment: Is $[(1−y)^{x}]|_{0}^{1}=(1-1)^{x}-(1-0)^{x}=-(1)^{x}$, then $I = \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{x+1}$ @ThomasAndrews

Comment: It was $2(1-y)^x,$ so the integral is $\frac{2}{1+x}.$ You dropped the $2.$ The $2$ doesn’t go away. @ManuelTorres